# C/C++ Posix BSD Sockets - HTTP Requests Always Return Status 400

Tags: c, sockets, http

I am learning to use native sockets in C and C++ on an OS X machine. From a previous project I have set up a very simple webpage at http://castifyreceiver.com/index.html. This webpage does almost nothing anymore so I don't mind sharing the real URL.

Basically my problem is that all my HTTP requests are returning 400 Bad Request. I know that the webpage I am using for this practice is up and running, and I am able to reach it through a browser. This leads me to believe that I am implementing the HTTP protocol incorrectly, but I don't know where I am going wrong.

The following is all of the code I am using to request this page over a socket.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

//  create the request
const char * request = "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1\nAccept: */*\n\n";
size_t length = strlen(request);
printf("request:\n\n%s", request);

//  get the destination address
struct addrinfo hints;
memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
struct addrinfo * address;
getaddrinfo("castifyreceiver.com", "http", &hints, &address);

//  create a socket
int sfd = socket(address->ai_family, address->ai_socktype, address->ai_protocol);
int result = connect(sfd, address->ai_addr, address->ai_addrlen);
if (result != 0) {
    printf("connection failed: %i\n", result);
    freeaddrinfo(address);
    close(sfd);
    return 0;
} else {
    printf("connected\n");
}

//  write to socket
ssize_t written = write(sfd, request, length);
printf("wrote %lu of %lu expected\n", written, length);

//  read from socket and cleanup
char response[4096];
ssize_t readed = read(sfd, response, 4096);
printf("read %lu of 4096 possible\n", readed);
close(sfd);
freeaddrinfo(address);

//  display response message
response[readed] = '\0';
printf("response:\n\n%s\n", response);

return 0;
}
```

This program consistently outputs something similar to the following:

```
request:

GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*

connected
wrote 38 of 38 expected
read 590 of 4096 possible
response:

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Thu, 05 Nov 2015 18:24:08 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.31 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.31 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips    mod_bwlimited/1.4
Content-Length: 357
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand. <br />
</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.31 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.31 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4 Server at 108.167.131.50 Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

I have spent a lot of time looking over [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.txt) and I still can't find what I'm doing wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things:

- You MUST send a `Host` header, cf. RFC 2616 p. 129:

  > A client MUST include a Host header field in all HTTP/1.1 request
  >       messages . If the requested URI does not include an Internet host
  >       name for the service being requested, then the Host header field MUST
  >       be given with an empty value.
- Use `\r\n` to terminate your lines in HTTP instead of just `\n`, cf. RFC 2616 p. 16:

  > HTTP/1.1 defines the sequence CR LF as the end-of-line marker for all
  >   protocol elements except the entity-body (see appendix 19.3 for
  >   tolerant applications). The end-of-line marker within an entity-body
  >   is defined by its associated media type, as described in section 3.7.

It should work if you change that.